# ¿Cual función del módulo random me permite generar un número de x cifras dadas como argumento?

Tags: python

La función debe generar un numero aleatorio de una cantidad de cifras dadas. 
Ejemplo:
Si quiero un numero de `4` cifras podría generar el `4698`, de `5` podría ser `10096` y así...

Answer (score 2):

Dado que decir un número (en base 10) cuya cantidad de cifras sea `n` es equivalente a decir:

Un número que está entre [image: 10^(n-1)] y [image: 10^n-1]

Podes usar `rand.randrange(inicio, fin)`

```
import random
n=5
i=10**(n-1)
f=10**n-1

print n, i, f, random.randrange(i, f)
```

Generalizando: un número entero en base `b` con `n` "dígitos" está en el intervalo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No existe ninguna función Built-in (que yo sepa) que lo haga, tendrías que crear tu propio código.

Una manera de hacerlo sería:

```
from random import randint
if digitos == 2:
    resultado = randint(10, 99)  # desde, hasta
elif digitos == 3:
    resultado = randint(100, 999)  # desde, hasta
elif digitos == 4:
    resultado = randint(1000, 9999)  # desde, hasta  
print(resultado)
```

Es un poco básico pero no creo que necesites complicarte mucho más.

Comment: Perdón, si bien es básico, seria un poco complicado trabajar de esta forma cuando una opción(por ejemplo) podría ser 13, o 14, o 15,.. , etc. Todo bien hasta ahí, pero el problema seria hacer una comparación para cada ocurrencia que haya. Se volvería moroso escribir el código para cada caso.

Comment: Depende de la necesidad del código. Si yo fuera a utilizarlo para solamente esas 3 opciones no me complicaría más.

Comment: Si, la idea es armar un juego donde el jugador debe indicar la cantidad de digitos que va a tener el número que despúes deberá adivinar...

Comment: Entonces mejor utiliza la respuesta de @aloMalbarez, es la mas corta, optima y elástica a tus necesidades. Solo recomendar no desbordar la memoria. Este problema se da cuando no tienes controles sobre los rangos que usas.